# GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso) does not exist

Tags: get, client, google-signin

I have problem, when i tried to make google authentication **.getClient(this, gso)** steel red and alt+enter does not help!

I tried to make the same in new, clear project, but nothing changed(

````
private void CreateRequestGoogleSignIn() {
        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions
                .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        

    }```
````

Answer (score 1):

Declare mGoogleSignInClient as an object of GoogleSignInClient like this before you initialize it

```
private lateinit var mGoogleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient
```

then you can use it as you did, like `mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)`

Also don't forget to import GoogleSignInClient

```
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in this line of code:

`mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);`

and i **change** this line:

`mGoogleSignInClient = com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);`

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency in the build gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0'
```